# Is the adjective “nothing loath” still in common usage?

Tags: word-usage

Google  Ngram Viewer shows a decline in the use of “nothing loath” since the 1970s unlike its  antonym “loath” which is still widely used.

Would it be appropriate for me to use it or has it become obsolete?

Comment: 'nothing loath' is an adjective?

Comment: It's certainly unknown to AmE speakers; I can't tell you how well known it is to BrE speakers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to look at [one chart](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nothing%20loath,nothing%20loth&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) to answer the question. Note the variant spellings, which have declined in lockstep over the past century...

[image]

But I would also point out that at least *some* of the "contemporary" instances will actually be citing earlier usages, so the decline is in fact steeper than the chart would suggest.

Having said that, the expression is at least "known" to many native speakers. But that doesn't mean it's "current" in natural speech. On the rare occasions when people use it (in speech *or* in writing) today, it's usually somewhat "facetious" (effectively, a deliberate archaism).

Also note that it's a "set phrase" that doesn't reflect modern grammar. You could reasonably (if "mock-archaically") say *"Our waiter was nothing loth to accept a handsome gratuity"*, but you certainly couldn't say he was *"nothing unwilling"*, for example.

Comment: The expression is certainly *not* familiar to *this* native speaker. It is regional? If I heard it, I would think that either the speaker had mis-spoken or I had mis-heard. Unless it was immediately clear from the context, I also think I might struggle to understand what was intended.

Comment: @TrevorD: Methinks perhaps we don't have a common understanding of the word *familiar*. Presumably you didn't look at the first word in this comment and think *Blimey! I've never seen **that** word before!*. I'd have thought if you read anything earlier than today's newspaper you can hardly avoid coming up against it now and then. I didn't say ***everybody** knows it* - my whole point is ***hardly anyone** uses it*. Maybe less than 50% of adult Brits actually know *of* it, I don't really know (I couldn't believe less than 30%, anyway). Most native native Anglophones on ELU though, surely.

Comment: @FF Methinks we probably do have a common understanding of *familiar* - but maybe not of *most*?! I agree that theoretically *most* means >50%, but methinks that in practice it is probably more often used to mean, say, >75%. I certainly didn't understand you as saying "everybody knows it", and maybe I am in a minority. I was stating - and perhaps over-emphasising - that I had never heard it (as far as I can recall). I also wondered whether it's regional - either between countries (e.g. UK - US), or within a country.

Comment: @TrevorD: Okay, I'll change it to *many*. I notice that again you refer to *hearing* the expression, whereas I'm mainly thinking in terms of people *reading* it. It certainly wouldn't be used in "natural" speech by many if any people today, and to be honest I wouldn't actually bet my £1 at odds of 50-50 that more than half of all native speakers would say *"Yes, that term is **familiar** to me"*.

Comment: @FF I suppose I wrote "heard" thinking that it's an informal term and is more likely to be heard than read, but, in practice, I meant that I had neither heard nor read it (as far as I can recall).

Comment: @TrevorD: But you must have at least *read* usages like [...which I was not loath to accept](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+was+not+loath+to+accept%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (or heard them on TV historical dramas, etc.). Maybe you never did come across the *"nothing"* variant. Or maybe different people react differently to "strange" grammar. I doubt I've read it *that* often, even at my age - and I can't swear I've ever heard or uttered it facetiously. But the non-standard grammar makes it stand out to me, so I couldn't easily not notice, or forget it.

Comment: @FF I'm certainly not saying that I'm not familiar with the word *loath* nor its common usage, because I am! All along, I've merely meant that I've never come across the expression *nothing loath*, and would not necessarily realise that it means *not loath* unless that were abundantly clear from the context.

Comment: @TrevorD: I can't think of many other contexts (modern ***or*** archaic) where "nothing" is used in this way to mean "not at all". I guess maybe *"What do you think of my new car?"* - *"Not much - it's **nothing special.**"*.

Comment: @FF Yes. I hadn't thought of that analogy.

Answer (score 2):

The Ngram Viewer gives this:

[image]

[image]

However, searching for the phrase "nothing loath" on Google Books returns several results from the twentieth and twenty-first centuries that use the phrase. The ones from early in the twentieth century seem legitimate works, but later results seem mostly to be dictionaries or reprints of older works (e.g. the Iliad). The OED, however, does not have any citations after 1873 - technically 1852.

I think it safe to assume that the phrase has fallen out of use, though I don't think its meaning would be terribly hard to discern for someone who hasn't heard it but knows the meaning of "loath". ("He was nothing loath to do something." "He was not loath to do something.") I don't for that reason really want to discourage you from using the phrase.

EDIT: I included the phrases "not loath" and "not unwilling" in my Ngram search this time, and got these results.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Phrase derives from Milton's Paradise Lost, was picked up in eighteenth century in heightened diction (literary), and eventually became more common still.  "Not unwilling" the present counterpart that might still be in wider use;  the more literary "nothing loath" will be so arch now that even in UK not current.